# Portable Linux webserver that does not require sudo, install, and internet

Tags: linux, rhel, webserver, apache-httpd, lighttpd

I have a corporate Red Hat Server that does not have sudo, package manager, and internet network. I need a webserver client, and have tried installers and binaries of httpd and lighttpd but references to /usr/sbin/httpd for instance, were still needed. That requires sudo. Is there anyway I can have a webserver running with my constraints? My port is above 1024.

My current workaround is to use another Windows machine as the httpd server to redirect to DNS to this Red Hat server.

Comment: Any webserver should do. It's just a question of configuration.

Comment: Do you have access to a similar system (distribution and version) where you can install or build packages?

Comment: @ThomasErker unfortunately I do not have another Red Hat - tried that route. Thus I was seeking advice here on alternatives. Would that eliminate the need for sudo for access to /usr/sbin/httpd? I don't think so.

Answer (score 3):

```
python -m http.server
Python version 3: Serve current directory tree at http://$HOSTNAME:8000/
```

Reference: [mattcurry.com](http://mattcurry.com)

Comment: SELinux and the firewall on a RH system would likely block this.

Answer (score 3):

I doubt very much that you will be able to get a webserver running on this Red Hat system. It appears to have been 'locked down' so in addition to the issues you have already identified you will have to deal with the following:

- RH systems have SELinux enforcing by default and given that this system is 'locked down' I would expect it to still be enforcing. With SELinux in enforcing mode httpd can only connect to ports specified in http_port_t (80, 81, 443, 488, 8008, 8009, 8443, 9000) so you get a choice of 4 > 1024.
- The stock firewall on a RH system only allows specified ports and blocks all others. The chances that any of the 4 ports you can use being open are slim to non-existent.

Answer (score 1):

*Note: I just saw in a comment that you did even have a `gcc` compiler. I'm afraid my answer will be quite useless in that case but again, without the basic development tools, you might want to consider the idea that the real problem is coming from somewhere else...*

You do not need root access to install a webserver. You can easily install lighttpd in your home directory, without accessing any restricted location on your system. The only trick is: you'll have to compile it by hand (yet, compiling lighttpd really isn't long).

1. Download/obtain [lighttpd's sources](http://www.lighttpd.net/download/).
2. Extract them.

```
$ tar -xvf lighttpd-*.tar.gz
```

3. Enter the directory you just created by extracting, and configure the building process using the `configure` script.

The trick here, is to use a different install prefix, and perform the install at an available location (your home directory).

```
$ mkdir ~/lighttpd
$ ./configure --prefix=$HOME/lighttpd
```

4. Build everything using `make` and perform the install using `make install`.

```
$ make
$ make install
```

Note that the last command (which usually requires root privileges since it installs files in `/sbin`) doesn't fail here. Now that lighttpd is installed, go to `~/lighttpd` and get ready to start your server.

5. Create a default configuration file for lighttpd.

Creating a configuration file in `~/lighttpd/etc/` and a document root directory at the same time:

```
$ cd ~/lighttpd
$ mkdir etc www
$ emacs etc/lighttpd.conf
```

Feel free to use your favourite editor, and write some default configuration in the file:

```
server.document-root = "/home/you/lighttpd/www/" 
server.port = 3000

mimetype.assign = (
    ".html" => "text/html", 
    ".txt" => "text/plain",
    ".jpg" => "image/jpeg",
    ".png" => "image/png" 
)
```

6. Go back to `sbin` and check your configuration:

```
$ cd ~/lighttpd/sbin
$ ./lighttpd -tf ../etc/lighttpd.conf
Syntax OK
```

7. Start your server.

```
$ ./lighttpd -Df ../etc/lighttpd.conf
```

With our configuration, the server should be available at http://localhost:3000/, and its document root located at `~/lighttpd/www`. Fore more details, have a look at [their configuration tutorial](http://redmine.lighttpd.net/projects/lighttpd/wiki/TutorialConfiguration), or just [their documentation in general](http://redmine.lighttpd.net/projects/lighttpd/wiki). lighttpd is pretty easy to setup, and I'm sure you could go with the same procedure (`./configure --prefix`, `make`, `make install`, read the docs) with other servers (even though they might require some more time and tweaking).

<sub>*Note about server administration:* if you're in a company with an IT department, leave the IT problems to them. They should make sure, in the first place, that you have all the tools you need, and if they don't want you to compile a server and make it listen on a port, then they should have configured their infrastructure accordingly. The compilation process I describe here has no reason to fail without root privileges, and you should have no problem running the server on a high port. Of course, it is likely that this server will remain hidden on the local network, and unreachable from the outside, but if they doubt so much about their infrastructure that they wouldn't let any computer open a port for listening over their own LAN, then they have much more pressing matters to take care of than that of a lighttpd install made by a user.</sub>

Answer (score 0):

You can have a webserver, but without root access it can't be at port 80. Anything under 1000 needs root permissions. Your could have 8080, or almost anything above 1000.

You will have to build from source if you can't use the usual package manager, thought I do recall that it's possible to have a package manager keep it's cache in a different place. The problem is that the usual setup assumes basic root access, so you would need to configure thing more by hand.

Comment: updated my question to reflect port. I also do not have c compiler because I can't install that, thus was looking at binaries

Comment: If you don't have a c compiler there, you will have to build one on another machine.

If there is a business case for you have these capabilities, I'd suggest you talk to someone in charge. This is getting absurd.

Comment: It's a highly secure server, so I don't agree it is absurd. Even if I build one on another machine, I still do not have sudo for /usr/sbin/httpd.

Comment: The absurdity is that you are trying to build things on a server where the sys-admin in charge clearly doesn't want you or anyone else building stuff. If this is needed for the business, make the business case to that person or their boss.

Comment: @George If it is a "highly secure server", I am sure there must an IT security procedure to be followed to even _allow_ such a software on that machine. Are you sure you will not infringe corporate policy and get yourself into a lot of trouble?

Comment: @HackSaw I'm looking for a solution, and not advice on the business. Before seeking approval for a deviance, a developer needs to do his due diligence and be absolutely sure that an approval is absolutely required for the case, which I disagree with your absolute that it's not possible.

Comment: @Dubu There's a big difference between running a webserver service on sudo rights, for instance, vs one that that is portable and contained. I'm clear on the policy, so no worries about that.

Comment: You describe this as a "highly secure server". As someone who has been on both sides of the IT fence, I can assure you that if I had found that a coder had installed a webserver on something I had demarcated as "highly secure", the next step would be a chat with their boss and HR. I'm not trying to rain on your parade, I'm trying to make sure you understand that you might be doing something which could get you fired.